# What approach should I take to handle non-generic exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

I have written code in which, for defensive purpose, I enclosed all method bodies in `try-catch` capturing generic `Exception` in `catch` block.

Now I have written method that accepts object of type `Exception` and then logs base exception type, exception message and stack trace. It then iteratively goes through the inner exceptions and prints the same for them. So in short whatever exception occurs anywhere, I get base type,   message and stack trace of all nested exceptions in my logs.

I have catched non-generic exception at all places where Visual Studio gave me warning as exception uncaught. But these are very less in number.

However their are instances in test-runs that on call to method:

> ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems()

I got following stack trace

```
2014-03-18 16:59:09.3816 | Error | The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server 

                  Immediate Stack Trace 
===================================================================================
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException : The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, ViewBase view)
   at com.cos.method() in c:\SW\Class.cs:line 268


     Inner Exception 1 : Stack Trace
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)


     Inner Exception 2 : Stack Trace
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.40.7.29:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) of this method do not specify that it can throw `ServiceRequestException` nor Visual Studio shows any warning.

Also, my company's automated code analysis tool generated huge amount of warnings for such generic exception catch blocks.

How should I be handling such occurrences of exceptions?

Comment: `Also, my company's automated code analysis tool generated huge amount of warnings for such generic exception catch blocks.` Because you probably should not have them. If you cannot do anything meaningful with an exception, let it bubble up and have a central handler that logs them. Why log them in 1000 different places? Just log them centrally. Even worse is swallowing exceptions and returning `bool`.

Comment: My code execution goes through method calls in different classes handling functionally different tasks. So letting bubble was complexing things since there were no logical hierarchy in those classes. Instead I called common method `logStackTrace` and passed `Exception` instance to it, so that if I have to handle exceptions differently I can just change that method. Also in class X, all `catch` blocks in all methods called `diagnose(X,Exception)` method so, if I have to handle those exceptions in class X differently I can change this specific method. No bubbling, but still central handling.

Comment: Might be a valid approach, but it destroys some important benefits of exceptions. Consider wrapping exceptions in module-specific exceptions and bubble those (e.g. `throw new MyComponentException("...", inner);`). Bubbling is very helpful to back out in case of error. Did you consider this? Would it be an adequate solution? You central handler can interpret the type of the exception and conclude from which module it came.

Comment: the point is I dont have business-specific custom exceptions. As you can see `ServiceRequestException` is environment-driven exception and also is not specified in MSDN. How can I know what all environment-driven exceptions particular method can throw to catch them. In this case I came to know after its occurrence in logs. Point is less about precise exception handling **approach**, but more about handling what all **specific** exception should I handle.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how your handling code looks like? I'm unclear at the moment about what concrete problem you have. Why is the current approach not working?

Comment: Nope its not like current approach is not working. Its working perfectly as I desire. But their are two problems: **(1)** The automated code analysis tool says I should not directly handle the generic `Exception`. And I may have to fix this up before I get security approval for this code **(2)** I am unable to figure out what  specific exceptions my code can throw (as in case of `ServiceRequestException`), even though I am able to get the specific exception through generic `Exception`s' inner exception property.

Comment: Please post some code. For (2): Why do you want to even find out if you're not doing specific handling anyway?

Comment: hmm (2): that's what even I was asking to our security team :p

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your entire workflow in a try-catch often seems like the best way to prevent unexpected exceptions from crashing code or causing unexpected down stream affects.  Often times it's a layer of security that obscures how you are actually handling specific exceptions for known issues.

### Bubbling Up

As far as a standard for when to bubble up and when to catch an exception, look to your workflow, it may not make sense to catch an exception in a lower level method when a higher level may have a better context to make decisions on how to handle specific excpetions. for example I may let an arithmetic function throw an exception unhandled so that i can catch it in a the service that calls it, that will know better, how i should handle that particular exception, perhaps i'll call a different function, or pass back a refined exception message, etc.  all of these options would not necessarily be available or make sense in the low level method.

### Multiple Exception Handling

When you do catch exception it's often a best practice to catch specific excpetions and provide individual handling for each exception type for your example above ServiceRequestException generic handling might look like this.

```
try{ 
//Do Your Work
}
catch(ServiceRequestException srex)
{
//Handle this Specific Exception Type
}
catch(StackOverflowException soex)
{
//Handle this Specific Exception Type
}
catch(SomeOtherSpecificException sose)
{
//Handle this Specific Exception Type
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
//Handle an Unexpected Exception
}
```

In this exception definition I order my exception by most specific to least specific.  I did include the generic exception at the end, while it is always preferable to catch just the specific exceptions that are expected, for some use cases preventing any exception from escaping might be a top priorty, web development for example will never want an exception to escape, to improve the user experience.  If you do have to cathc generic excpetion make sure you have proper Exception Logging.

### Exception Logging

It sounds like you got a logging methodology already, but i'll mention this anyways.  There are a lot of great logging options out there for .NET log4Net and Common.Logging are ones i use frequently.  There are also Exception Specific loggers such as Elmah. An important thing to look for, is that you logging allows you to specify various levels, and methods of communication.  This will allow to to apply granularity to your exception management, so exception especially ones you expect could happen, may take a lower priority to generic excpetions.  Being able to pop the exceptions that aren't properly handled to the top, or use email or a more direct form of exception communication will help you better respond to Exceptions, and implement better exception handling in your code.

if you do find unexpected exception be sure to add a specific catch method for them, with exception specific handling. Hope this helps.  Here is a code project article with a lot more 1337 pro tips on exception management, the ones i've mentioned here i think match your question the best, but the article is a worthwhile read too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET#Don%27teverswallowexceptions13

Comment: as far as your second point, of how could you know about that the ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems() method would throw the ServiceRequestException.  

if it's not stated in any of the documentation, which as you show it is not, it is probably excepting on an underlying call inside that method rather than explicitly where documentation would see it.

In this case, you would probably have to implement some form of Unit Testing or regression testing, to perform positive and negative tests, which could uncover this exception.